# Finding the most frequent number(s) in a c++ vector

Tags: c++, vector, numbers, element, frequency

New guy here, and a rookie programmer. Can anyone give me an idea how to finish up my program task I gotta do?

So first the user has to input the length of the vector, afterwards input the elements themselves (elements can be only between 0 and 9).

Then the console has to print out the most frequent number and the number of times it occurs. But in case of multiple numbers with the same maximal frequency, it has to print all of them, ordered from smallest to
largest.

So far, so good, I've managed to do it for an input like this:

"13

4 1 1 4 2 3 4 4 1 2 4 9 3"

And have an output that says that 4 is the most frequent, occurring 5 times.

But for:

"11

7 7 7 0 2 2 2 0 9 9 9"

I sadly hit a wall and cannot think of a simple way to tackle this.

Thank you in advance to whoever decides to read and lend a hand!

> Blockquote

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> 
#include <vector>

int main()
{
int i = 0;
int length;
int elements;

std::cout << "Enter length and elements of array: ";
std::cin >> length;
if (length < 0) { std::cout << "Don't be naughty now!"; return 0; }

std::vector<int> arr;
arr.reserve(length);
for (int i = 0; i<length; i++)
{
    std::cin >> elements;
    if (elements > 9 || elements < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Input can be only between 0 and 9.";
    }
    else
    {
        arr.push_back(elements);
    }
}
std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());
int counter = 0;
int element = 0;
// std::vector<int> mostFreqNums;
for (auto i : arr)
{
    int tempElement = i;
    int tempCount = 0;
    for (auto j : arr)
    {
        if (j == tempElement)
        {
            tempCount++;
            if (tempCount >= counter)
            {
                element = tempElement;
                counter = tempCount;
            }
        } 
    }
}
//for (auto p : mostFreqNums)
//{
    std::cout << "The number " << element << " is the most frequent (occurs " << counter << " times).\n";
//}

return 0;
```

}

> Blockquote

Comment: You don't need to store all the inputs. Consider a collection of ten elements, each of which is a counter, and see where it takes you

Comment: If you don't have to use a vector, you can simply use an array, make an array of size `10` all initialized to `0`, which has index `0` to `9`. After that simply increment each related array item. For example if you have two fours, do `a[4]++` twice.

Then you can simply check which array value has highest and print that index.

Comment: Use a map with the input data as index and the number of occurrences as value. Then search for the index with the highest value. No need to store them all, only count them up. Maps are dynamic. No limitation on the number of entries.

Answer (score 0):

This pseudo code might help.

```
/*a counter for each number 0-9*/
unsigned char counter[10U];
/*keep track of maximum occurrences.*/
unsigned char max_count = 0U;
unsigned char i;

for (i = 0U; i < your_array_len; i++)
{

   /*Don't access array out of bounds...*/
   if (your_array[i] >= 0U && your_array[i] <= 9U)
   {
       counter[your_array[i]]++;

       if (counter[your_array[i]] > max_count)
       {
           max_count = counter[your_array[i]];
       }
   }
}

for (i = 0U; i < 10U; i++)
{
    if (counter[i] == max_count)
    {
        printf("Found %u occurrences for number %u\n", counter[i], i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally did it! I will refactor and make it simpler and prettier, but just wanted to share it here first. Thank you everyone for helping me solve it!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> 
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int length = 0;
    int element = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int largest = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int arr[10] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    std::cout << "Enter length and elements (can be between 0 and 9 only): ";
    std::cin >> length;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        std::cin >> element;
        if (element < 0 || element > 9)
        {
            std::cout << "Don't be naughty now!\n";
        }
        else
        { 
            arr[element]++;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == arr[i + 1])
        {
            counter++;
            if (counter > largest)
            {
                largest = counter;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == largest)
        {
            printf("The number(s) %u occur(s) %u times\n", i, arr[i]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
vector <int> v;
    // add some elements
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(3);
    v.push_back(1);

    int maxCount = 0, mostElement = *(v.begin());
    int sz = v.size(); // to avoid calculating the size every time
    for(int i=0; i < sz; i++)
    {
        int c = count(v.begin(), v.end(), v.at(i));
        if(c > maxCount)
        {   maxCount = c;
            mostElement = v.at(i);
        }
    }
    cout << "the number appeared the most is " << mostElement <<"\n";
    cout << "it appered " <<maxCount<<" times";
```

note: you can use the following for loop to avoid any iterator overflow if the size of the vector can't be held by an integer:

```
    for(auto it= v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++)
    {
        int c = count(v.begin(), v.end(), *it);
        if(c > maxCount)
        {   maxCount = c;
            mostElement = *it;
        }
    }
```